How to add tasks out of emacs when using org-mode as task manager
I would love to use emacs + org-mode as my task manager (currently using RTM). However, one piece that I am missing is to easily be able to add new tasks from outside emacs. Specifically, there are 3 places where many of my tasks currently come from:

Browser: Currently have a bookmarklet which when pressed will create a task with the current page that I am viewing's title and url.
Slack: Hitting "Save for later" button in Slack, creates a new task with the message details. I do this via Zapier intergration.
Mobile: RTM has an app with an Android desktop widget that I use to add tasks. I've tried to use Orgzly and Orgro plus Dropbox but they are both much better at reading then writing.

I was wondering of someone has been able to figure out innovative solutions to address these gaps.
Thank you

Can't help with 2) or 3), but for 1), the usual method is an org-capture template plus org-protocol - see Protocols for external access in the manual and search for it on the web (including this site).

An orgfile is just a text file, which means you can append text using any method that allows adding text to a file.
I use Kupfer to append text, i.e, add a new task to my org file from anywhere on my desktop / laptop
On my android mobile, I use Markor's (a wonderful app) quicknote feature to do the same thing. Using text expansion software allows you to add the leading stars, properties etc.
This is the nice thing about org. Since it's just a text file, you don't need dedicated apps to simply add text to it.

Do you mean Kupfer launcher? Could you add a bit more detail on how you use that to add a new tasks? Markor seems very promising. I currently use Dropbox, but it seems that I need to check out Syncthing to sync changes. I'll give that a try.

Yes, kupfer launcher. Open preferences, go to plugins and enable a plugin called textfiles. This allows append and append to functions. Also don't forget to index your org files under Catalog, in preferences. Now when you call Kupfer, hit period / fullstop key. This allows text string insertion. Add your leading stars for the heading level you need and type text, tab to the action section, type append to, and then tab to the target section and type the filename of the org file. That's it.

Please add all these details to your answer. Don't put them in comments.
